# get the download id for the product in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce in wordpress . I have set 2 files to download  for each product  but when I am trying to call the both the download file link using the below code :

```
$download1=$product->get_files();
```

I am getting the following array:

```
[downloadable_files] => Array
        (
            [d289633f5c2d8f2f7cc9a102aea7242c] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Three Phase UPS1
                    [file] => http://localhost/creative/wp-content/uploads/woocommerce_uploads/2014/11/SolaPalm_DS.pdf
                )

            [413ff459269b8ed9e7c441eac585c035] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Three Phase UP2
                    [file] => http://localhost/creative/wp-content/uploads/woocommerce_uploads/2014/11/CFL_DS.pdf
                )

        )
```

While I want to get download id for individual file
so that i can use the for loop to get all the download product link.

Comment: Just to be clear - the array you display is what you get when you var_dump($download1) ?

Comment: According to the manual (http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_productget_files/) it seems that both of those files are related to the current product.

Comment: @OfirBaruch yes , both of files are related to current product , as the website demands 2 pdf for each product

Comment: so what's the problem? You have an array with the downloads. You can use a simple `foreach` loop and print them, or I'm missing something?

Comment: can you plz show me some example because I am also confused , to how to show all the pdf name with link

Answer (score 1):

The Woocommerce method is get_downloads() :

```
$product = wc_get_product($product_id);
     $downloads = $product->get_downloads();
     foreach ( $downloads as $key => $download ) {
         echo $key // gives - d289633f5c2d8f2f7cc9a102aea7242c
         echo $download["name"] // gives - Three Phase UPS1
         echo $download["file"] // gives - http://localhost/cre...
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$downloads = $product -> get_fields();
foreach ( $downloads as $key => $download ) {
   $key // gives - d289633f5c2d8f2f7cc9a102aea7242c
   $download["name"] // gives - Three Phase UPS1
   $download["file"] // gives - http://localhost/cre...
}
```

This should give you what you need

Comment: have a look here for the correct answer http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/199884/revisions

Comment: The previous link will bring you to the revisions page, this is the proper link that should've been posted instead: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/199877/what-is-the-code-to-get-the-download-link-for-a-product-in-woocommerce/199884#199884